# Using the IVP definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$, how can we show that $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x) = 1$ without any "magic"?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definition, alternative-proof

One way to define the exponential, hyperbolic and circular functions is to assert that they're the unique solutions to certain IVP systems:

The exponential function:

$$\exp'(x) = \exp(x), \qquad \exp(0) = 1$$

Hyperbolic functions:

$$\cosh'(x) = \sinh(x)$$

$$\sinh'(x) = \cosh(x)$$

$$\cosh(0) = 1$$

$$\sinh(0) = 0$$

The circular functions:

$$\cos'(x) = -\sin(x)$$

$$\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$$

$$\cos(0) = 1$$

$$\sin(0) = 0$$

> **Question.** Using the IVP definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$, how can we show that $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x) = 1$?
>
> I'm looking for a satisfying proof that I can present to young people, so:
>
> - no complex numbers, and
> - no power series, and, more generally
> - no "magic"!
>
> In fact, the closer the proof is to being "just plain algebra", the better.

*Motivation.*

There's a geometric way of defining the circular functions: first, position yourself at $(1,0)$ on the unit circle. Then start walking anticlockwise at unit speed. It follows that if the time elapsed is $t$, your $x$-coordinate will be $\cos t$ and your $y$-coordinate will be $\sin t$.

The above information can be organized into four statements:

1. We walk on the unit circle centered at the origin.
2. We position ourselves at $(1,0)$ to begin with.
3. We walk at unit speed.
4. We walk anticlockwise.

These can be formalized as follows:

1. $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$
2. $\cos(0) = 1, \sin(0) = 0$
3. $(\cos't)^2+(\sin't)^2 = 1$
4. $\sin'(0) > 0$

Now conditions 2 and 4 follow easily from the IVP definition. Furthermore, if we can show 1, then 3 follows easily. But, I haven't been able to show 1 in a "non-magic way" e.g. without complex numbers.

Comment: If you know that $\cos'=-\sin$ then you just have to differentiate the function $\cos^2+\sin^2$,see it is constant, etc. Is this too magical?

Comment: @GitGud, no! That's wonderful.

Comment: but I don't see the point trying to define $\cos,\sin$ non-geometrically... you want to make your students your ennemies ? 90% of them will hate you... even you (the teacher), you have some difficulties defining $\cos,\sin$ this way !!!

Comment: And the other 10%, like you and me, Goblin, will remember you for the rest of their lives for giving a definition that's much, much easier to work with and approximate to a formalization.

Comment: @GitGud : how is that much easier to work with? Can you give a formula for $\cos(a+b)$ starting from this definition?

Comment: @Tryss: $\cos(x+a)$ is a solution to the same differential equation as $\cos(x),\sin(x)$ but with different initial values. Consequently $\cos(x+a)=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$ for some $A,B$ which can be found by checking initial values.

Comment: @GitGud, thank you for the kind words :)

Comment: @Semiclassical, nice approach. I just used this to check that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ and it seems to work. I wonder if we can use this approach to say anything interesting about $\cos(xy)$?

Comment: @GitGud, a cool feature of your approach to showing $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ is that, if we try it on the hyperbolic functions, it fails to work, but more to the point its "obvious" why it fails to work, namely that there's a negative missing, which allows us to conjecture $\cosh^2-\sinh^2 = 1$ as the correct formula, and this is easily verified. So your method actually "teaches" us something that we may not have known previously (if we're e.g. high school students.)

Comment: @Semiclassical, do you know what the name of the theorem is that tells us that the vector space of solutions to the system $c' = -s, s' = c$ is two dimensional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)$ we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right) = \sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos(x) = 0 $$
hence $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$ is a constant function, equal to $\sin^2(0)+\cos^2(0)=1$.
This easily gives 1.,2. and 3. and 4..

Comment: I don't know why it took my so long to accept this. Seems pretty clear!